# How to override a method and chose which one to call

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, neural-network, overriding

I am trying to implement Neural Network from scratch. By default, it works as i expected, however, now i am trying to add L2 regularization to my model. To do so, I need to change three methods-

cost() #which calculate cost,
cost_derivative ,
backward_prop # propagate networt backward

You can see below that, I have  `L2_regularization = None` as an input to the **init** function

```
def __init__(self,sizes, activations = None , cost_function = 'binary_cross_entropy' ,param_init_type = None, L2_regularization=None,dropout = None):
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.caches = dict() 
        self.cost_function = cost_function
        
        if activations == None:         self.layer_activations = self.default_layer_activations_init(sizes)
        else:                           self.layer_activations = activations
        

        if param_init_type == None:     self.param_init_type = 'default' 
        else:                           self.param_init_type = param_init_type
        self.parameters_initializer()
```

So, if L2_regularization is True i need slight changes in abovementioned methods.

I can copy all three functions and change them and while training ask about:

```
if self.regularization:   cost =  self.cost_reg(input) # as if i'm overriding the cost function
```

as well as for other ones

**However**,

There are two problems with this way

1. I don't see this way as a really pythonic way of doing it. So, it doesn't look good when copying one method and giving it another name with slight changes.
2. I don't want to check whether `self.regularization is True` or  `self.regularization is None`: in each iteration.
   I think it could slow down the model and there is a better way instead. If i am wrong let me know about this problem.

What I want from model is to be aware of regularization beforehand.

For example, I have `self.regualrization==True`

when i call backprop method in train function, it returns back propagation with regularization expression

## Code.

It would be too complicated for you to read the whole code and advise me a way of doing things as i want. Hence, i wrote simpler code with same scenario actually

```
class Network():
    def __init__(self,sizes, regularization = None):
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.expression = 5 
        self.regularization = regularization


    def compute_cost(self):
        count = 0 
        for i in self.sizes:
            count+=i
        return count

    def compute_cost_regularized(self):
        count = 0 
        for i in self.sizes:
            count+=i

        #as if self.expression is value of regularization expression 
        count = count + self.expression

        return count
    
    def cost_value(self):
        if self.regularization:
            return self.compute_cost_regularized()
        else:
            return self.compute_cost()



net_default = Network([3,3,4])
net_regularized= Network([3,3,4],regularization=True)

print('This is the answer from net_default ',net_default.cost_value())
print('This is the answer from net_regularized ',net_regularized.cost_value())
```

The output is :
This is the answer from net_default  10
This is the answer from net_regularized  15

It doesn't solve none of my problems.

I wrote one method 2 times with 1 line change and i used if statement while computing.

How can i write it without doing this. And do i need to avoid using if statement in each iteration

I also tried to override the method

```
class Network():
    def __init__(self,sizes, regularization = None):
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.expression = 5 
        self.regularization = regularization


    def compute_cost(self):
        count = 0 
        for i in self.sizes:
            count+=i
        return count
    
    def cost_value(self):
        if self.regularization:
            return regularized(self).compute_cost()
        else:
            return self.compute_cost()

class regularized(Network):
    def __init__(self, sizes, regularization=None):
        super().__init__(sizes, regularization)
    def compute_cost(self):
        return super().compute_cost() + self.expression


net_default = Network([3,3,4])
net_regularized= Network([3,3,4],regularization=True)

print('This is the answer from net_default ',net_default.cost_value())
print('This is the answer from net_regularized ',net_regularized.cost_value())
```

However, I got an error TypeError :  'Network' object is not iterable

Here is the actual train() and cost() function if you have modification idea for implementing regularization

```
def cost(self,X,Y):
        #TODO L2 reg ll change cost function
        """param X : Input that will be given to network , Function itself does forward propagation steps and compute cost
           param Y : Wanted output corresponds to given input data. Cost will be computed by This Y and Y_hat which is output of NN for X input"""
        Y_hat = self.feed_forward(X)
        m = Y.shape[1]
        
        if self.cost_function == 'binary_cross_entropy':
            cost = (-1/m)*np.sum( np.multiply(Y,np.log(Y_hat)) + np.multiply( (1-Y) , np.log(1-Y_hat) )) ; cost = np.squeeze(cost)
            return cost
        elif self.cost_function == 'mse':
            cost = (1/m)*np.sum(np.square(Y-Y_hat)) ; cost = np.squeeze(cost) 
            return cost
        else:
            raise Exception('No such cost function yet')


def train(self,X,Y,lr = 0.0001,epoch=1000 , X_test = None , Y_test = None , regularization  = None , dropout = False):
        assert (X.shape[1] == Y.shape[1]) , "Unmatched In out batch size"
        self.caches['A0'] = X
        for iter in range(epoch):
            A_l = self.feed_forward(X)
            dA_l = self.cost_derivative(A_l,Y)
            for layer_num in reversed(range(1,self.num_layers)):
                grad_w,grad_b,dA_l = self.backward_prop(dA_l,layer_num)
                self.update_param(grad_w,grad_b,layer_num, lr = lr)
            if iter% (epoch/10) ==0:
                print('\n COST:::',self.cost(X,Y),end=' ')    
                self.score(X,Y)
                                                                                                                                               
        if X_test is not None:
            self.score(X_test,Y_test)

        #Saving parameters dictionary to file 
        a_file = open("parameters.pkl", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.parameters, a_file)
        a_file.close()
```

Just in case you are interested, I have uploaded the full code here.

https://github.com/IlkinKarimli0/Neural-Network-from-scratch/blob/main/NeuralNetwork.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General

Overall you should not create an object inside an object for the purpose of overriding a single method, instead you can just do

```
class Network():
    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.expression = 5 

    def compute_cost(self):
        count = 0 
        for i in self.sizes:
            count+=i
        return count
    
    def cost_value(self):
        return self.compute_cost()


class RegularizedNetwork(Network):

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        super().__init__(sizes)

    def compute_cost(self):
        return super().compute_cost() + self.expression


net_default = Network([3,3,4])
net_regularized= RegularizedNetwork([3,3,4])

print('This is the answer from net_default ',net_default.cost_value())
print('This is the answer from net_regularized ',net_regularized.cost_value())
```

In other words you actually create an instance of your child class, which overrides a specific function (here: compute_cost), and inherits all the remaining ones. Now when cost_value() is called, it will call the corresponding compute_cost. In fact you do not need compute_cost either.

```
class Network():
    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.expression = 5 

    def cost_value(self):
        count = 0 
        for i in self.sizes:
            count+=i
        return count


class RegularizedNetwork(Network):

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        super().__init__(sizes)

    def cost_value(self):
        return super().cost_value() + self.expression


net_default = Network([3,3,4])
net_regularized= RegularizedNetwork([3,3,4])

print('This is the answer from net_default ',net_default.cost_value())
print('This is the answer from net_regularized ',net_regularized.cost_value())
```

## Code issue

If for some reason you would like to continue with your own code, the issue is that here

```
    def cost_value(self):
        if self.regularization:
            return regularized(self).compute_cost()
        else:
            return self.compute_cost()
```

you are passing reference to "self" to a constructor of `regularized` which is expecting `sizes`, it should be

```
    def cost_value(self):
        if self.regularization:
            return regularized(self.sizes).compute_cost()
        else:
            return self.compute_cost()
```

Comment: You were quicker to post the answer, I was going to say the same :)

Comment: In the real code, I have 15 methods. Is it okay to override certain functions and inherit all the remaining ones? which will be 12 methods to inherit

Comment: Yes, this is a standard practise to override a few functions and inherit everything else.